# Method not allowed error (405) Mojang API

Tags: java

´

I am currently working on a project where I am trying to log the player in through the mojang API but it returns an error (405) Method not allowed (seems like it somehow thinks I'm sending a GET request instead of a POST)

Would be glad if anyone could help me out.

Here is the source code for the auth request:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import net.sxlver.accountchecker.exception.AccessDeniedException;
import net.sxlver.accountchecker.manager.OutputManager;
public class AuthRequest {
   
    private OutputManager outputManager = new OutputManager();
   
    /**
    * 
    * @param username
    * @param password
    * @return required JSON Object containing the credentials and a few other information the API needs as String
    * @throws JSONException if JSONObject contains invalid data
    */
   
    public String MakeJSONRequest(String username, String password) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
        json1.put("name", "Minecraft");
        json1.put("version", "1");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("username", username);
        json.put("password", password);
       
        return json.toString();
    }
   
    /**
    * 
    * @param url
    * @param content
    * @return the API's response as String (JSONObject)
    * @throws AccessDeniedException if the provided credentials are invalid
    * @throws IOException if any issues are encountered whilest preparing and/or sending the request
    * @throws JSONException 
    */
   
    public boolean httpRequest(URL url, String content) throws AccessDeniedException, IOException, JSONException {
        byte[] contentBytes = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
       
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(contentBytes.length));
       
        String response = "";
        BufferedReader responseStream;
        if(((HttpsURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode() == 200) {
            responseStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        }else {
            responseStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(((HttpsURLConnection) connection)
                    .getErrorStream(), "UTF-8"));
        }
       
        response = responseStream.readLine();
        responseStream.close();
       
        if(((HttpsURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode()!=200) {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(content);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Invalid JSON request. Could not parse content to JSONObject.");
                return false;
            }
            outputManager.print("Access denied for " + json.get("username") + ":" + json.get("password") 
            + ". Response code: " + ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode());
            return false;
        }
       
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note: I have already done a lot of debugging and the provided credentials are working and they're not formatted wrong.

Fix: I have added the following lines

```
OutputStream requestStream = connection.getOutputStream();
requestStream.write(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.length);
requestStream.close();
```

Comment: Mh there isn't an actual error thrown by my code but, on httpRequest the API returns the code 405 (Method not allowed) where it was supposed to return 200. This is all information i got. I don't know if it also returns the error as a JSONObject but if it does i could let it print it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the request method in `HttpURLConnection` instance, default value is `GET`.

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Comment: @Sxlver now your pervious error resolved , but you have some problem in your data you send.

Comment: @Sxlver check your json  format and the data you should send

Comment: Yea I will check it as soon as I’m back home. But the code I posted up there has worked for me In previous projects too smh. I will double check my request later on.

Comment: ty for helping, i have found a solution after combining your solution with a bit of other code.